# Insert and Retrieve in iOS (Core Data )

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am trying to insert the data into `CoreData` iOS. For that i have created the below function in separate file called **DatabaseOperation**

```
+(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
return context;
}

+(void)storeCodeSearchData:(NSMutableArray*)data{

for (NSDictionary* rowData in data) {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    // Create a new managed object
    NSManagedObject *codeSearchDataObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:CODE_SEARCH_ENTITY inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [codeSearchDataObject setValue:[rowData objectForKey:SKU_CODE] forKey:CODE_NID];
    [codeSearchDataObject setValue:[rowData objectForKey:NID] forKey:CODE_ID];
    [codeSearchDataObject setValue:[rowData objectForKey:NEEDLE_DESCRIPTION] forKey:CODE_NEEDLE_DESC];
    [codeSearchDataObject setValue:[rowData objectForKey:NEEDLE_DIMENSION] forKey:CODE_NEEDLE_DIMENSION];
    [codeSearchDataObject setValue:[rowData objectForKey:SUTURE_TYPE] forKey:CODE_SUTURE];
    [codeSearchDataObject setValue:[rowData objectForKey:SIZE] forKey:CODE_SIZE];
    [codeSearchDataObject setValue:[rowData objectForKey:FOILS_PER_BOXEX] forKey:CODE_FOILS];
    [codeSearchDataObject setValue:[rowData objectForKey:HOSPITAL_PRICE] forKey:CODE_RETAILS_HOSPITAL];
    [codeSearchDataObject setValue:[rowData objectForKey:MAXIMUM_RETAILS] forKey:CODE_MAX_RETAIL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL *saveResult = [context save:&error];
    NSLog(saveResult ? @"Yes" : @"No");
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (!saveResult) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
  }  
}
```

`NSLog` is printing `"Yes"`.
I am calling this function from other `implementation` file like below:

```
[DatabaseOperation storeCodeSearchData:datas];
```

My `datas` is a `NSMutableArray` which is storing the `NSDictionary` like below:

```
NSMutableDictionary *resultantDataObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 resultantDataObject[KEY1] = @"nc";
 resultantDataObject[KEY2] = @"c";
[datas addObject:resultantDataObject];
```

But when i am trying to fetch the data its `null`. Below is the method to get the data which is i am using:

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [DatabaseOperation managedObjectContext];

   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:CODE_SEARCH_ENTITY];
            NSDictionary *datasAA = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
            NSLog(@"Data Retrieve: %@",datasAA);
```

**Thanks for help**

Comment: From what I see you may want to add a predicate to your fetch request and also an NSARRAY is returned, not an NSDictionary when executing the request.

Comment: @Volker I want to store the data and retrieve it. I didn't get you

Comment: See how to fetch objects from core data: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html

Comment: @Volker Thanks for response. Could you please tell me here what i am doing wrong.

Comment: When you check the link you will see an example for a fetch request. Try to do your request after adding a predicate as seen there. And also note that an NSArray is returned .